# if condition: (64 > 360) is true?

Tags: javascript, math

I have a bit of code in Javascript, which returns true when it obviously shouldn't. For context: I have a mindmap and in order to find the most extreme coordinates of the map, I cycle through all nodes and check if this node has a higher/lower value than the currently highest/lowest value. When running the code the method returns wrong values and with console.log() I think I found something weird, but don't know how to fix it.

```
findMaxX(maxX){
        console.log("this.x before test:"+this.x);
        console.log("maxX before test:"+maxX);
    if (this.x > maxX){
        console.log("this.x:"+this.x);
        console.log("maxX before:"+maxX);
        maxX = this.x;
        console.log("maxX after:"+maxX);
    }
    this.children.forEach(element => {
        maxX = element.findMaxX(maxX);
    })
    return maxX;
}
```

What I find in the console is this:

```
maxX before test:360
this.x before test:288
maxX before test:360
this.x before test:64
maxX before test:360
this.x:64
maxX before:360
maxX after:64
this.x before test:65
maxX before test:64
```

It seems to be working just fine, but at some point the condition seems to return true for an obviously false statement. Is there some noob mistake I'm doing? Where can I search for errors? My code looks fine to me and I can't see a connection to the observed error. I'm happy for all hints! Thank you

Comment: I would guess this is a type issue, if your values are stings your `>` will not give the same result as for numbers.

Comment: Maybe `this.x` or `maxX` can be `string`. If so the condition may not work as expected

Comment: Just use === operator when compare.

Comment: It would help if you shared example values and how you get them

Comment: yes you were all right, I thought javascript recognizes numbers on its own, but it seems like it doesn't. I now use Number() to make sure the saved coordinates are numbers, thanks to everybody!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that this.x and maxX could be strings. And that's why you obtain these results. Here you can see these examples (run this code snippet):

```js
let xNumber = 64, yNumber = 360;
let xString = "64", yString = "360";

console.log(xNumber > yNumber);
console.log(xString > yString);
```

And read some information about the comparison of different types in JavaScript [here](https://javascript.info/comparison)

Also, as a suggestion to obtain what you need (if you want to compare these variables as numbers), I would advise converting them to Number, for example in this way:

```js
if (parseFloat(this.x) > parseFloat(maxX)) {
  // here your code
}
```

Comment: use parseFloat here since you said that you're working with coordinates